# How do I make a highlight element scroll with the page?

Tags: html, css

I just got into web development and I'm currently trying to make myself a portfolio page.
However, I'm getting a problem (rather unimportant, but still, I would like to fix it) where the highlight element (the circle that makes the grid in the background clear) is misaligned when you scroll down but goes back into place when you scroll back up.
You can see the glitched page [here](https://www.cocolennon.xyz/glitched) and the source code is [here](https://github.com/Cocolennon/cocolennon.github.io/tree/main/glitched).
Any help is well received.

**Attempt, Expectation and Result**
I tried making a highlighting element which makes the background clear inside of it.
I expected it to scroll along with the page without misaligning.
The highlighting element misaligns whenever you scroll down.

PS: If the glitched page is gone, it means my problem is solved.

Comment: I still haven't found how to fix that